# begged to decline

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anyone help me about the exact meaning of the words in bold?

Jack's embassy contact, John, **begged to decline**.

I shouls add that jack proposed an idea that John could not accept it.

Comment: Where does this come from? When was it written? What have you found when you looked up *beg* (or *beg* + infinitive) in a couple of dictionaries? For example, Lexico/Oxford has ["beg to second the motion"].

Answer (score 1):

It means he very very politely refused - or possibly, that he had no intention of accepting the suggestion, but humorously pretended to be very polite about it.

"Decline" here means "refuse an invitiation". "Beg to decline" is a (now very old-fashioned) way of softening this for politeness' sake: the implication is that you're very apologetic about declining, so you are begging the other person to allow you to decline.

Comment: Thanks very very much, thanks a million. You saved my lide!

Comment: @Arya It's really no different than *beg to differ*. Although that's something of a set phrase, you can, in reality, *beg to [whatever]*, even if some replacements there might sound strange and would normally not be used.